# how to define a variable in one file and use it in another one

Tags: c, linker, header-files, runtime-error, extern

The question may be very basic but I am not getting clue anyways ...

I have two files ...
and I am mentioning what I want to do .

**file 1**

```
...
j = data->alloc_len;
...
```

**file 2**

```
...
  for(i=0;i<j;i++)
...
```

Its clear from above I want to assign value to a variable in one file and want to use that value in other file.

I tried `#include "file1.c"` in file2.c but it is giving lot of re-declaration errors.

I tried creating a seperate header file which only have one line `int j` and then included it in both files using `extern` but no benefit again.Although I think header files are meant for where i can create and assign a value to a variable in one file and then this value can be propogated to all other files by including this one.

May be I am wrong but I need it soon so please help me ...Thnx in advance.

**Limitation -**

The value can be assigned only through `file1.c` because `data` structure is declared and defined here only.I can not provide a value to `variable j` in a header file .

**EDIT :**

Although I mentioned but I think I could not clear my question.I have tried using it header files.

For debugging purpose I tried this ..

**sample.h**

```
 extern int j;
```

**file1.c**

```
 #include "sample.h"
 int j=245;
```

**file2.c**

```
  #include "sample.h"
  printf("%d",j);
```

but its getting error .

Error I am getting is :

```
    Couldn't open module sample.so, tried:
sample.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./sample.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/lib/sendip/sample.so.so: 
    cannot open shared object file: No such file or     
    directory
/usr/local/lib/sendip/sample.so: undefined symbol: j
```

**none of the file contains main function actually **

Actually it is a very large project and I am using `Makefile` and all files will be linked at run time.

In short,the execution could be understood as there is a `main.c` file which contains `main` which in turns call `file1.c` and which in turn calls `file2.c`

About descriptive names I would say they are just for showing here otherwise I am already using descriptive name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* put this in a header file:

```
extern int j;
```

and only declare the "real" `j` in file1.c. If file2.c includes that header, then it can use variable `j`.

**But**, use descriptive variable names a the very least for globals. And you should avoid globals as much as you can, they are a liability in the long term, IMO.

(You could consider something like making a function in `file1.c` that returns that value. This has the advantage of assuring that `j` is controlled in `file1.c`, and only read in other places, limiting the complexity of understanding who "owns" that variable.)

Comment: Can you show some code using function .. may be that could work out

Comment: `int getJ() { return j; }` in file1.c, `int getJ();` in file1.h. Just saw your edit - you have to make sure that both your C files get linked into the library.

Comment: `int getJ();` in file1.h giving error `samp.h:1:1: error: function declaration isn’t a prototype`

Comment: compiled but again same error `undefined symbol getJ`.I am so much confused what should I do please suggest me or tell me some other way.

Comment: You're not linking your shared object correctly. Can't tell what you're doing wrong without seeing your compile/link commands.

Comment: also both files are linked perfectly when I remove this code for `j` or `getJ`.

Answer (score 1):

like this

in the c file you define the variable say file1.c you write

```
int j;

...

j = data->alloc_len;
```

a header for your file1.h would contain

```
extern int j;
```

this header you include in file2.c

```
#include "file1.h"
```

but i would suggest using a more descriptive variable name.

Answer (score 0):

`#include "file1.c"` is almost never the correct solution to a problem. Invariable you want to be declaring things in header files and then defining them in just a single source file.

**file1.h**

```
extern int j;
```

**file1.c**

```
#include "file1.h"
j = data->alloc_len
```

**file2.c**

```
#include "file1.h"
if (j>0)
    ...
```

Having said all of this, I would strongly council you to pass values as parameters rather than use global state. Global state is evil. Avoid it like the plague.